# ajuda a como armazenar imagem no banco de dados mysql e exibi-las no index

Tags: mysql

Testei esse código que achei, é o index, nele exibo produtos do meu banco, só a imagem que é a mesma (se repete em cada div) porque não pego ela do banco, acho que se eu pegasse a imagem como pego o preço e o nome do banco de dados resolveria, mas como posso fazer isso, por favor?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <img src="img/produtos/buque-dia-radiante.jpg" alt="" />
                             <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $product['nome']?></h4>
                             <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
                                R$<?php echo number_format($product['preco'], 2, ',', '.')?>
                             </h6>
                             <a class="btn btn-primary" href="carrinho.php?acao=add&id=<?php echo $product['id']?>" class="card-link">Comprar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, você dar uma olhada aqui: https://www.devmedia.com.br/armazenando-imagens-no-mysql/32104 é um artigo falando sobre armazenamento de imagens no mysql.

Outra alternativa é usar API do imgur (https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest) , onde vc passa a imagem e eles salvam no banco deles, dessa forma, vc só precisa guardar o ID da imagem no seu banco e dps usar a mesma API pra recuperar a foto. Agora vc tenq ver o que vai te dar menos dor de cabeca, usar uma API pra gerenciar suas fotos, ou voce mesmo guardar ela..